# Swap output 5Vdc - GND

Tags: mosfet, analog

I'm looking for a "circuit swapper"; basically I need to change the voltage reference on "out1" and "out2". I have an input signal that changes periodically, so i.e. input = 0, out1 = 5V, out2 = 0V; input = 1, out1 = 0V, out2 = 5V. I'm worried about the transition between the swap..
hope the question is enough clear.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: So a 2 input, 2 output, mux?

Comment: What is the input, what are the outputs? It seems from your question that all three are digital signals?

Comment: @ Harry Svensson, thank you for your reply. Yes, I think it could be! I try to explain better how the circuit should works.
The swapper should have a "state change detection" function, and flip/swap the output when the state has changed, then do it again.
Is this possible with a mux?I was thinking to use a Flip Flop, what do you think? thanks

Comment: @ Tom Carpenter, Yes, digital signals, 0V - 5V

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you're describing is this:

[image]

Here's a [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+63+5+50%0Af+864+304+912+304+0+1.5+0.02%0Ag+912+368+912+384+0%0AM+1008+256+1040+256+0+2.5%0Aw+848+352+976+352+0%0Aw+976+352+976+176+0%0Aw+976+176+832+176+0%0Aw+912+320+912+368+0%0Ar+912+240+912+192+0+10000%0Aw+800+176+864+256+0%0Aw+864+256+864+304+0%0Aw+832+176+832+352+0%0Ax+751+255+805+258+4+24+out1%0Ax+1013+233+1067+236+4+24+out2%0Ax+748+157+809+160+4+24+input%0AL+800+176+768+176+0+0+false+5+0%0AM+816+272+784+272+0+2.5%0Aw+912+272+816+272+0%0Aw+912+272+912+288+0%0Aw+864+256+1008+256+0%0Aw+912+240+912+272+0%0AR+912+192+912+144+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ao+2+64+0+4098+5+0.1+0+1%0Ao+15+64+0+4098+5+0.1+0+1%0Ao+14+64+0+4098+5+0.00009765625+0+2+14+3%0A) if you want to test it and verify it (Click on the input L/H). And it's not a double mux which I thought you first was interested in, it's a simple logic inverter with the wires drawn where they should go.

And here's a truth table (with logic ones and logic zeros), one that would help you and everybody else a lot.

```
input | out1 out2
-----------------
  0   |  1    0
  1   |  0    1
```

When input is a logic 0, out1 is a logic 1 and out2 is a logic 0.
When input is a logic 1, out1 is a logic 0 and out2 is a logic 1.

Which one is easiest to understand? The minimalistic graph or the text?

Comment: @EnricoPallazzo Just mark it as your answer. Otherwise this will pop up in 2 years as a question unsolved.